# Does a ring map $f:R\to S$ induce a homomorphism $GL_n(R)\to GL_n(S)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $R$ and $S$ be commutative rings with $1$ and $f:R\to S$ a ring homomorphism. Does $f$ induce a group homomorphism $GL_n(R) \to GL_n(S)$?

#### Progress

I first consider the map $\bar{f}:M_n(R)\to M_n(S)$ given by letting $f$ act on the matrix elements. Using the formula for the determinant, I obtain $\det(\bar{f}(A))=f(\det(A))$. Am I on the right track?

Using Jyrki Lahtonen's hint, I now see that if $A$ is invertible then $f(\det(A))$ is a unit of $S$. So $\bar{f}$ maps $GL_n(R)$ into $GL_n(S)$.

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck? Does you definition of ring homomorphism include the condition $f(1)=1$?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track.

Comment: What do you mean by $det$ if $R$ is not commutative?

Comment: Remember that for a matrix over a commutative ring to have an inverse it is necessary and sufficient that its determinant is a unit of the ring.

Comment: You can define ${\rm GL}_n(R)$ for any ring with $1$, including non-commutative rings, as the group of units of the matrix ring $M_n(R)$. You don't need the determinant for that.

Comment: This might not be a helpful way to think for you but I believe $GL_n(R)$ is given by a $\mathbf{Ab}$-valued functor, and so a ring homomorphism would induce a group homomorphism.

Comment: @DerekHolt: But the hints, including the one now cited in the question, only prove that $GL_n$ is a functor from _commutative_ rings to groups. It may or may not be true that it also defines a functor from (unitary) rings to groups, which would be an additional, interesting, question. If true, the proof seems harder than in the commutative case; maybe relevant is that Mac Lane's book gives $GL_n$ as an example of a functor $\mathbf{CRng}\to\mathbf{Grp}$.

Comment: @Dom: what category is $\mathbf{Ab}$? Last time I checked $GL_n$ was non-Abelian whenever $n>1$ (and the ring is non-trivial).

Comment: You are right I probably meant to say $\mathbf{Grp}$ - I shouldn't comment when I'm tired. $\mathbf{Ab}$ would just be Abelian groups. Can't comment to amend original comment any longer.